# ARCGIS for Javascript : Clustered layer with changing icons at different zoom levels

Tags: javascript, esri, arcgis-js-api

So, I have a map that shows RSS News Items by state.

When I am zoomed in, I see the icon of the source news outlet: Reuters, Yahoo, Fox, CNN.

What I need is a clustering layer that shows generic, clustering icons at high zoom levels but shows the source icons when zoomed in enough for the space between icons is clearly defined.

I have tried to augment existing clustering layers to accept the specific icons to no avail.

Has anyone done this before?

I can't imagine this has not been done in the past.

Any directions on where to find the answer would be appreciated.

Comment: whatever you have tried yet... create fiddler for that.. that will help us to provide solution...

Comment: The online example already uses renderers.  Was that not sufficient?
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=layers_point_clustering